# d3 - accessing the data behind the area I clicked

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple app that I have based on an existing d3 chart - [parallel sets](https://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/) by Jason Davies

I want to extend what the chart does by trapping the click event and using the "event" data to populate a table with the data that supports the visualisation.

I can access the data (and in particular the path) ***but I am doing this in a very clunky way:***

```
var pathForClickedArea = event.path[0].__data__.path;
```

This gives me the path: dimension dimension2 dimension3 (or a combo that reflects where I clicked)

I would like a better way to get at the data. Some documents speak of d (or datum) but this always seems to be null?

My code is as below:

Adding click handler:

```
d3.select("#vis")
.on("click", onclick)

function onclick(d, i){
  // d is always null 
  var d2 = d2 != null ? d : "no value";
  var pathForClickedArea = event.path[0].__data__.path;
  console.log(pathForClickedArea);
}
```

This returns (in the browser console):

[image]

**How should I be retrieving this path/data?** (instead of `event.path[0].__data__.path`)

Comment: Skip the `onclick` variables - you don't need them. Try `d3.select(this).data()`

Comment: Thanks @RyanMorton. Unfortunately that didn't work. (Undefined). Also I am looking specifically for the data relating to the segment that was clicked - why the path is what I need - just must be a better approach to accessing it. Thank you

Comment: Then I'd attach the click event to the path not to whatever `#viz` is.

Comment: Tx, will try - viz is the div that hosts the d3 visualisation: var vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg"). <div id="vis"><noscript><img src="parsets.png"></noscript></div>

Comment: I understand. From the documentation, I think you should be able to select the paths instead of the whole viz and attach the listener.

Comment: Thanks Ryan:     d3.selectAll("path").on("click", function (d, i) { console.log(d.path) });